# Pagination in Spring Boot not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, pagination

I'm building small TODO project using JavaScript, Ajax and Spring Boot. I did make all CRUD operations, tested them and they work.

Now I blend in pagination using Spring Boot, like so:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/" )  
public Page<Task> getAllTasks(
                @RequestParam(value = "page", required = true) Optional<Integer> pageNumber,
                @RequestParam(value = "date", required = true) String date){
    
            Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber.orElse(0), TODOS_PER_PAGE); //TODOS_PER_PAGE=2
            LocalDate localDate = parse(date);
    
            return taskService.getAllTasksByDate(localDate, pageable);
        }
```

I have following data:

Exactly six `TODO` records with their title from `do a` to `do f`, with indexes from 1 to 6.

This is the UI in the browser once the page first time loads.
[image]

Now, in JavaScript, I made some constructor function called Page, so I can keep reference on current page. Kinda to mimic `static` in Java.

It looks like this:

```
function Page() {
    this.someNonimportantProperty = "";
}
```

Now, once the page first time loads, I set property of prototype called `pageNumber`, as I explaind above. The first time loading of a page will bring me two `TODO`s object, along with information whether it is the last page or not.

Each time I  click `Load more todos` button, "static" `pageNumber` variable increases and I get following two entities. Increasing of variable looks like this:

```
Page.prototype.pageNumber = Page.prototype.pageNumber + 1;
```

Here is the problem:

Once I click second time, on my UI I have `do a`, `do b`, `do c` and `do d`. Next I delete `do b` and `do c`. I do remove the from UI and logically delete the from database, like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE task SET active = false WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "active = true")
public class Task { ...}
```

Now in UI, I have `do a` and `do d`. Here comes the problem. In my database I'm sure I have `do e` and `do f` not deleted, but once I click for the second time on `Load more button`, the `pageNumber` is equal to 2 (which is okey) and in my response I get that the page is last, but I get an EMPTY Json array! Drives me nuts!

[image]
Next, if I load page one more time, those last two elements `do e` and `do f` get fetched from db.

Here is how my Ajax GET request looks like:

```
function triggerGetRequest(pageNumber) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',  // http method
        url: window.location + "api/tasks/?page=" + pageNumber + "&date=" + convertDateToString(new Date(datepicker.value)), //endpoint on our backend
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            
            
            resolve(data)
        },
        error: function () {
            reject("error on server...")
        }
    });

})
```

}

These is the function which gets called on button click:

```
    function loadmore(event) {
    Page.prototype.pageNumber = Page.prototype.pageNumber + 1;
    console.log(Page.prototype.pageNumber)

    triggerGetRequest(Page.prototype.pageNumber)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)

            dynamicallyUpdateDOM(transform(data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: When you delete the record in `UI` did you change page number as well ?Also how you come to know next which record to fetch because you said again you click on load more button its fetching correct record ? so next value will be `3` ?

Comment: @Swati No, when I click Delete, that div, or what ever is removed from DOM and DELETE request (with appropriate Id) get sent to backend to do deletion. This first time page loads (like: $(function(){...})) Page.prototype.pageNumber gets initialized to 0, and every click increases that variable. Paging in Spring Boot starts from zero.

Comment: without deleting any record does the code works as accepted or not ?

Comment: @Swati Yes, that is correct. If I just ask for next "page", I get what I need. Initially, a and b, first click -> c and d, second click -> e and f. What I'm starting to ask myself, is Paging in Spring Boot meant for this kind of things, or it has to be implemented in a different manner...Hope someone will get a hang of this stupidity...

Comment: so i think problem is somewhere in deleting process . Make sure when you delete and then click load more correct values get pass to your backend or maybe there is problem with pageno or date value.Also , make sure in backend as well `pageno` is correct or not which you have in spring boot . Sorry , I have limited knowledge in spring :) .

Comment: @Swati No way there's problem in deletion. I console.log-ed every time, number for first click is 1 and for the second click (the one that should return 5th and 6th record) is 2. I just don't understand why that json array is empty after deletion.